# Actionscript 3, flex: How to find out which is browser you are currently in?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, browser, mxml

I need to detect via AS3 inside flex mxml appication which is browser I am in - FF, Chrome, IE etc, only name and version. How to do such thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you're going to use javascript, but you dont actually need to put javascript in the page.

Here's a quick script example of getting that information from your flex app without adding anything to the containing html page:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
          creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            var appName : String  = String(ExternalInterface.call("function(){return navigator.appName}"));
            var appVersion : String  = String(ExternalInterface.call("function(){return navigator.appVersion}"));
            var userAgent : String  = String(ExternalInterface.call("function(){return navigator.userAgent}"));
            trace( appName ) ;
            trace( appVersion );
            trace( userAgent );
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

This traces the info out to the console, so for example when I run it I get :

```
Microsoft Internet Explorer
4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; GTB6.6; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; GTB6.6; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
```

Let me know if you have any issues!

Comment: Thanks for the accept.  P.s. userAgent is the most reliable to key off your browser sniffing.  :)

Comment: `navigator.appName` returns `Netscape` instead of browser name.

Answer (score 1):

It's not tricky if you use some client side JavaScript and the ExternalInterface  class in the Flash library.

Here's a brief tutorial on doing that: http://codingrecipes.com/calling-a-javascript-function-from-actionscript-3-flash

Your JS would need to run a browser client check.

Answer (score 0):

As per my research `navigator.appName` will return string `Netscape` for browsers like: IE11, Firefox, Chrome and Safari. check [this.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_appname.asp)

If you want to detect browser name try this:

```
var browserName:String;
var userAgent:Object = ExternalInterface.call("window.navigator.userAgent.toString");

if(userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") !== -1)
{
browserName = "Chrome";
}

if(userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("mozilla") !== -1)
{
browserName = "Mozilla";
}

if(userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("safari") !== -1)
{
browserName = "Safari";
}
```

reference : [check visitor OS & Browser using as3](http://code.davemeddings.com/index.php/check-visitor-os-and-browser-from-as3/)